# Kubernetes Service load balance techniques

Tags: kubernetes

What is the algorithm used in kubernetes Service object when its doing load balancing between PODs. Like I have 2 instances running, and one Service is exposed for both of them. What is the default load balancing rule Service is using and how to customize that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubernetes Service load balancing is round robin by default. So requests to Service will be almost equally distributed between your pods.

You may configure `SessionAffinity` for Service. The only affinity technique availble is `clientIP`. Think twice before enabling `SessionAffinity` because in many cases it is practically useless.